# retrieve Firestore document from onCreate trigger with Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to retrieve information from a Firestore Document when another document is created. When I try to do this I get hit with an error about the function not being async. It has been so long since I used javascript I am basically a novice again and have no idea how to fix this.

ok, so I am using Firebase Cloud Functions and the function in question is a Firestore `.onCreate()` trigger.

When the function is triggered I set a `sender` variable (which is the document ID from a different collection that I need to retrieve)

then I try to get the document as per the documentation.

The function ends up like this:

```
exports.pushFriendRequestNotification = functions.firestore.document('friends/{friendID}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // when friend request is created
  
  data = doc.data()//get request data
  sender = data["sender"]//get request sender from data
  
const requestRef = db.collection('User').doc(sender);
const doc = await requestRef.get();//get user data of sender
if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
} else {
    console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    
            
}
});
```

when I run this in the emulator I get this error:

```
const doc = await requestRef.get();//get user data of sender
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

I have absolutely no idea where to go from here.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await` keyword is valid only in an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function.

```js
exports.pushFriendRequestNotification = functions.firestore.document('friends/{friendID}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        //  ^^^^^
  })
```

If you are (or need to) use synchronous function then you would have to use [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining).

```js
exports.pushFriendRequestNotification = functions.firestore.document('friends/{friendID}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
     return requestRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
       if (snapshot.exists) { ... }
     })
  })
```

Apart from that, the order of variables/statements looks incorrect. With the current code (as in original question), you may end up getting an error: *"Cannot access 'doc' before initialization"* Try refactoring it like this:

```js
exports.pushFriendRequestNotification = functions.firestore.document('friends/{friendID}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    // accessing data from newly created doc
    const newDocData = snap.data()

    // const sender = "" // ??
     
    const requestRef = db.collection('User').doc(sender);  
    const doc = await requestRef.get();//get user data of sender
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', doc.data());      
    }
  })
```

Where is the `sender` coming from? I've just commented it above but if the sender is present in new document then you can access it by: `const sender = newDocData.sender`

Comment: while every answer here gave basically the same answer, I've chosen to mark your as correct because you spotted the `doc.data()` mistake (thanks).... also sender was indeed present in the new document, I couldn't find the documentation on accessing specific fields in a document (it was 2AM, I was VERY tired hah).... I figured it was between `.sender` and `["sender"]` but you beat me to it :P ..... cheers :)

Comment: @Andy glad to hear that :D Checkout this [Firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk) for better understanding of Firestore triggers. Also `.sender` and `["sender"]` are same thing ([Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)). Your 'doc' would have been undefined.

Answer (score 2):

If your using await you have to specify that function is `asynchronous`. Otherwise it will throw error.

```
exports.pushFriendRequestNotification = functions.firestore.document('friends/{friendID}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    // when friend request is created
    data = doc.data()//get request data
    sender = data["sender"]//get request sender from data
    const requestRef = db.collection('User').doc(sender);
    const doc = await requestRef.get();//get user data of sender
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());      
    }
});
```

Yet some of your references is unknown to us. Maybe this code is not completed.

The main point is you need to understand when you can access [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1):

All await methods must be inside an async block or be handled in an async manor using `.then()` promises

in this case, the parent function is on this line `.onCreate((snap, context) => {`

simply inserting an async at the start of the variables will upgrade the arrow function to an async arrow function
`.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {`